# Create view with spatial query and limit results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, oracle-spatial

Oracle 12c DB with Locator...

I have 2 tables- table1 has a point geometry column.
Table2 has a polygon geometry column.
I want to create a view with only the table2 polygons that contain exactly 
1 point from table1. Is this possible?
I have tried the following but it still returns polygons that contain multiple points:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW VIEW1 AS
SELECT a.address, l.geometry as GEOMETRY
from table1 a 
inner join table2 l
on sdo_anyinteract(a.geometry, l.geometry) = 'TRUE'
having 2 >
(select count (a.address)
from table1 a 
inner join table2 l
on sdo_anyinteract(a.geometry, l.geometry) = 'TRUE');
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have primary keys in both tables(id)  ?

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz Yes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to just use a simple group by and count in the having clause

```
SELECT
    a.address,
    l.id
FROM
    table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 l ON (sdo_anyinteract(a.geometry,l.geometry) = 'TRUE')
GROUP BY
    a.address, l.id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as I would have to include l.geometry in the 'group by', which gives ORA-22901: cannot compare VARRAY or LOB attributes of an object type

Comment: Can you use l.id instead, which you would be able to use in the group by?  Then use the results to re-join to table2 to get the geometry?  (edited answer)